# Prevent onClick firing from overlapping components without preventDefault?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

[image]

I have a file chooser input that is placed over another element (the green square).  The green square has an onClick function that launches a modal.  When I click on the file input, two onClick events are being fired - one for the filer chooser and one for the green element behind it.

I want to prevent the green square element from firing an onClick when the file chooser is clicked.

IfI call event.preventDefault() from the onClick(), it prevents the green element onClick successfully, but also prevents the file chooser input from launching.

stopPropagation appears to do nothing.

This is in React.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stopPropagation() to handle that; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

```js
let fileChooser = document.getElementById('fileChooser');
fileChooser.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   event.stopPropagation();
   // ... your code
})
```

Comment: It's not working for whatever reason.  No matter where I put stopPropagation in the flow of onClicks, the underlying element always has its click fired.  UNLESS I put the stopPropagation so high up in the chain that it stops all the propagation (before the file chooser gets to fire onClick).

When I placed a debugger in the click event, debugger runs, hits the event.stopPropagation() line, and then if I hit "resume" to break from the code debugger code execution, the debugger catches again on the second onClick.  Very strange